# Mismatch between PoseProvider.GetPoseAtTime returned pose and poses returned in OnTangoPoseAvailable

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm querying the PoseProvider for a AD2Dev pose based on the timestamp returned in OnExperimentalTangoImageAvailable, and I'm seeing some strange results.

Logging the pose coming in via OnTangoPoseAvailable, I see results like this:

```
pose at time : 70595.754506

From Pose AD2Dev via callback
-0.2031748 -0.3201837 0.925312 -0.4358828
0.9790875 -0.0764451 0.1885304 -2.015653
0.01037121 0.9442661 0.3290197 0.1402309
0 0 0 1
```

I’m checking this by calling GetPoseAtTime with the same timestamp of the incoming pose, and get the same result:

```
from pose AD GetPoseAtTime
-0.2031748 -0.3201837 0.925312 -0.4358828
0.9790875 -0.0764451 0.1885304 -2.015653
0.01037121 0.9442661 0.3290197 0.1402309
0 0 0 1
```

The pose after this comes in looking like this:

```
pose at time : 70595.764504
-0.2031739 -0.3201777 0.9253144 -0.4358475
0.9790877 -0.07645106 0.1885275 -2.015655
0.01037896 0.9442677 0.3290148 0.1403415
0 0 0 1
```

In OnExperimentalTangoImageAvailable, I update the texture frame like so:

```
frameTimestamp = VideoOverlayProvider.RenderLatestFrame(TangoEnums.TangoCameraId.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
```

Which gives me a timestamp of 70595.755121338

Calling GetPoseAtTime for AD2Dev, I’d expect a resulting pose that lerps the two poses above.
However, I’m getting the following result:

```
TANGO_POSE_VALID 70595.755121338 TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE

-0.1990919 -0.3197772 0.9263396 -0.437389
0.9799466 -0.07286096 0.1854613 -2.02092
0.008187711 0.9446872 0.3278706 0.1360694
0 0 0 1
```

You can see the position is not between the two bounding poses, and the rotation is also quite different.

Can anyone explain what I’m doing wrong, or why the resulting pose coming back from GetPoseAtTime isn’t a direct lerp between previous and subsequent poses? Is there some form of back correction happening due to drift?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you're doing anything wrong. With "low latency mode" enabled by default, the pose from OnTangoPoseAvailable is rougher and less accurate than a pose acquired with GetPoseAtTime.

My understanding is GetPoseAtTime interpolates the pose based on the fisheye camera which runs at 30hz, as well as the IMU which runs at 100hz.

Because the IMU gathers more motion data in between fisheye poses, it's never going to be a straight linear interpolation. I also wouldn't be surprised if there isn't some spherical interpolation going on in between IMU data, in addition to auto correcting past tracking data with area learning turned on.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'll continue digging. The offset I get querying the AD2Dev pose in the texture callback is consistently different (quite radically so, on the order of centimeters sometimes), which is why I was surprised at getting an identical value (when I query using GetPoseAtTime) to the pose coming in via the PoseAvailable callback; I expected any sort of drift correction to be applied at that point too.  I'll gather more data and see if I can get a bit more insight.